# Rails 4: what is a good location for a method available in controllers, models and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I just migrate from cancan to pundit, and I enjoyed the cancan syntax to check authorization: `can? :show, @user`. With pundit, the same verification is written `policy(@user).show?`. I find it less readable. So I am writing a 2 small wrapper which are:

```
def can?(model, action)
  policy(model).send(action)
end

def cannot?(model, action)
  ! can?(model, action)
end
```

My question is: In Rails 4 what is the best location for the 2 wrappers, knowing that I am using them in controllers and views. Not yet in model but it could become the case later, so let say: everywhere.

- If I use view helper, they are available in views only
- If I use application controller helper, they are not available by rspec while testing views, and I trust will not be available in models

Any pointer appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to wrap them in modules. Write classes n modules and place your modules in application's `/lib` folder. that is the best place from where you can access them in your controller, views and models as well.
Modules are used for 3 different things in ruby. First is namespacing. Having class or constant definitions inside a module won't collide with classes or constants outside that module. Something like this

```
class Product
  def foo
    puts 'first'
  end
end

module Affiliate
  class Product
    puts 'second'
  end
end

p = Product.new
p.foo # => 'first'

p = Affiliate::Product.new
p.foo # => 'second'
```

The second use for modules is as a place to stick methods that don't really have a place anywhere else. You can do this inside a class too, but using a module sort of tells people reading the code that it is not meant to be instanciated. Something like this

```
module Foo
  def self.bar
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

Foo.bar #=> 'hi'
```

Finally (and the most confusing) is that modules can be included into other classes. Using them this way is also referred to as a mixin, because you are "mixing in" all the methods into whatever you are including.

```
module Foo
  def bar
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

class Baz
  include Foo
end

b = Baz.new
b.bar #=> 'hi'
```

Mixins are actually a way more complected topic then I am covering here, but going deeper would probably be confusing.

Now, to me, S3 seems to be something that really belongs in the controller, since controllers are usually the things dealing with incoming and outgoing connections. If that is the case, I would just have a protected method on application controller, since that will be accessible to all other controllers, but still be private.

If you do have a good reason for it being in the model too, I would go for a mixin. Something like

```
module AwsUtils
private
  def S3
    AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!\
      :access_key_id     => 'Not telling',
      :secret_access_key => 'Really not telling'

    data = yield
    AWS::S3::Base.disconnect
    data
  end
end
```

If you put that in lib/aws_utils.rb, you should be able to use it by adding include AwsUtils in both your controller and your model. Rails knows to look for classes and modules in lib, but only if the name matches (in wide case). I called it AwsUtils because I know what rails will look for when it sees that (aws_utils.rb), and to be honest, I have no idea what it will need for S3Utils.

Modules tend to be one of those things in ruby that while amazing, are downright baffling to newcomers.

Hope this suggestion will help you.Thanks.

Comment: Awesome it works! I've never been very good with module and this is the occasion to learn. I just created a module into app/helper (accessible in views + auto reload in development environment) and include it in `ApplicationController`. All good. However I assume I will have to include it in each of my model right? BTW I am not sure why you mentioned S3.

Comment: That's the part, I recently worked on that, so I wanted to make a complete clarification. Forget that part, if it's not your cup of tea, but if someone want to use AWS S3, it will be useful for them. Isn't it? :)

Comment: @RailsGuy This looks an awful lot like something I read here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562307/484689 in fact, its almost identical. I don't know who wrote it originally, perhaps it was you, or Matt Briggs or someone before that. Regardless, giving credit to the author of your answers is often considered a courtesy.